# nodejs mongo code does not work with new mongo version

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code works on mongo 2.4.9 but does not work on latest (2.6.7).

I am aware there's a dot issue in the keys, but I find it hard to believe that mongo broke backward compatibility like this

my question is can my customer somehow tweak mongo 2.6.7 to make it work? or is it a choice between changing the code or downgrading mongo?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    var blueprints = db.collection('blueprints');
    blueprints.insert({}, function( err, insertedList ){
        var insertedListId = insertedList._id;
        insertedList =  {"userId":"54eae2f9e9409b4c464f1499","nodesToSave":[{"width":140,"height":100,"id":1,"name":"Guy","type":"Root","uiType":"Node","x":340,"y":60,"infoData":{"properties":{},"interfaces":{"cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle":{"create":{},"configure":{},"start":{},"stop":{},"delete":{}},"cloudify.interfaces.validation":{"creation":{},"deletion":{}},"cloudify.interfaces.monitoring":{"start":{},"stop":{}}}},"templateData":{"type":"cloudify.nodes.Root"},"markedContainedIn":false}],"connectorsToSave":[]};
        insertedList._id = insertedListId;
        blueprints.update({ '_id' : insertedList._id} , insertedList , { upsert: true },function(){
            console.log('after update', arguments);
        });
        console.log('after insert',arguments);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`insertedList` is a beast to scroll through. FYI, if you go to JSONLint and verify the JSON, as long as it's not totally busted it will format it for you nicely, even if it's not valid JSON (e.g. it works for mongo shell BSON syntax):

```
{
    "userId": "54eae2f9e9409b4c464f1499",
    "nodesToSave": [
        {
            "width": 140,
            "height": 100,
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Guy",
            "type": "Root",
            "uiType": "Node",
            "x": 340,
            "y": 60,
            "infoData": {
                "properties": {},
                "interfaces": {
                    "cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle": {
                        "create": {},
                        "configure": {},
                        "start": {},
                        "stop": {},
                        "delete": {}
                    },
                    "cloudify.interfaces.validation": {
                        "creation": {},
                        "deletion": {}
                    },
                    "cloudify.interfaces.monitoring": {
                        "start": {},
                        "stop": {}
                    }
                }
            },
            "templateData": {
                "type": "cloudify.nodes.Root"
            },
            "markedContainedIn": false
        }
    ],
    "connectorsToSave": []
}
```

Looks like the problem is with `cloudify.interfaces.[lifecycle, validation, monitoring]`. Those are illegal field names - `.`' s are not allowed in field names. 2.6 enforces this strictly on updates.

As part of upgrading to 2.6, there is a function [`db.upgradeCheckAllDbs()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.upgradeCheckAllDBs/#db.upgradeCheckAllDBs) that should find issues like this. There's no fix except to remove such fields.